# Algorithm for price optimization

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, large-data

I'm trying to figure out a way for calculating price optimization in a commerce environment. In other words, I'm trying to analyze how a company can increase revenue and profitability by analyzing costs, customer buying behaviors, competitive activity, demand signals and historic data.

How can I come up with a strong algorithm to do this? Performance is not an issue since I'm looking to do analysis in a big data environment.

Comment: This is an extremely general and broad question and as such cannot reasonably be answered here. Please narrow it to a specific question (following the guidelines in our [faq]).

Comment: Yes, too broad a question, as whuber notes. You might get some ideas from the OR faculty at the Columbia U Center for Pricing and Revenue Management.   http://www7.gsb.columbia.edu/cprm/

Comment: In order to get a concrete answer, I suggest that you state as clearly as possible: what is the problem you are trying to solve, what is the input data you are using and what output you expect to get (and perhaps also your background). On a side note, performance is always an issue since many optimization problems are difficult/intractable, so the quality of the solution will improve with computation time.

Comment: How much do you want to bet that performance isn't an issue?

Comment: You might find this tutorial helpful. This explains price optimization through OR techniques and is in the language of SAS.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Kfe2FprUPA

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a forecasting question to me.

You can create greater optimisation on pricing, leveraging the front-facing staff through what-if scenarios.  This will give you all the insights you mentioned above, which you can then feed into your algorithm testing.